# Анимированное солнце со спутником вращающимся по орбите

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, webgl

У меня задача анимировать солнце.
Нужно, чтобы были всполохи и небольшие лучики. Лучики должны гореть, как пламя и медленно вращаться.
Технологии могут быть любые: SVG, SMIL, JavaScript, CSS, Canvas, WebGl, или что-то ещё.

Так же необходимо сделать одну планету вращающуюся вокруг солнца. Планета должна вращаться по такой орбите, чтобы она часть пути пролетала за солнцем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое можно сделать?

Принимаются ответы также с частичным решением. Например: без планеты или без лучиков.

Всего должно быть 3 элемента анимации.

1. Всполохи.
2. Лучики как огонь. Должны а) гореть б) Вращаться покругу.
3. Вращающаяся планета, где часть орбиты проходит за солнцем.

**PS:** Постараюсь подготовить своё решение, если смогу.

Comment: побалуюсь с этим на выходных :)

Comment: вспомнил, как то пилил планетки на enso https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665476/2393786

Comment: @Дмитрий Полянин Спасибо за интересный вопрос!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Вариант #2

C использование вращения **одного слоя** паттерна языков пламени и применение фильтра `feTurbulence` для создания колыхания протуберанцев солнца

Вращение паттерна:

```
.flame {
transform-origin: center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: rotate-sun 40s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-sun {
0% {transform: rotateX(0deg); }
100% {transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
}
```

Применение анимации фильтра `feTurbulence`

Настраивая значения `baseFrequency`, `numOctaves`,`scale="25"` добейтесь эффекта колыхания пламени по своему вкусу.

```
 <!-- Эффект колыхания огня для протуберанцов солнца -->
       <filter id="myFilter" >
      <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.0005" numOctaves="5" result="turbulence" >
     <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="32s" values="0.0005;0.02;0.0005;0.02;0.0005" begin="btn1.click" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
      </feTurbulence>
     <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter>
```

```css
.flame {
transform-origin: center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: rotate-sun 40s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-sun {
0% {transform: rotateX(0deg); }
100% {transform: rotateZ(360deg); }

} 


<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 10 200 200" > 

<defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow2" 
  x="-20%" y="-20%" 
  width="150%" height="150%">
  <feGaussianBlur   stdDeviation="2" />
  </filter> 
       <!-- Эффект колыхания огня для протуберанцов солнца -->
       <filter id="myFilter" >
      <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.0005" numOctaves="5" result="turbulence" >
     <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="32s" values="0.0005;0.02;0.0005;0.02;0.0005" begin="btn1.click" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
      </feTurbulence>
    <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter> 
       <!-- Анимация градиента языков пламени -->
   <radialGradient id="gradSun">
        <stop offset="20%" stop-color="yellow">
   <animate attributeName="offset" values="80%;20%;40%;10%;80%" begin="btn1.click" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="gold" >
  <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="gold;#FF6200;gold" begin="btn1.click" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </stop>
      </radialGradient>
      
      <!-- Градиент окраски вращающейся планеты -->
   <linearGradient id="gradEarth">
   <stop offset="40%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen" ></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>     
   
         <!-- Фон -->
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#321300" /> 
 
          <!-- Протуберанцы солнца 1-ая группа -->
  <path id="flame"  class="flame" fill="url(#gradSun)" filter="url(#myFilter)" d="m181.9 82.8c-27.3 31.7 13 43-4.1 40.5-9.2-1.4-38.7 12.5-18 26.4 20.5 13.7-30-2.1-20.1 12.9 14.2 21.5-18.3-8.9-23 9.3-7.4 28.2-10.9 1.8-16.6 1.8-6.6 0-13.6 13.2-19.2-2.4-3.8-10.7-27.1-14.7-33.7 3.2-3.2 8.6-10.1-48-13.3-39.3C19.4 174.7 36.3 104.4 26.1 108.6 0.8 119.1 33.6 83.8 32.5 75.7 30.3 59.4 20.1 39.8 24.6 45.2 32.4 54.4 52.8 48.8 48.8 43.5 36.6 27.5 38.2 21 36.2 18.9 19.8 1.4 76 39.7 74.2 33.7 71.5 25.1 68.3 8.7 70.3 10.1c7.1 5 29.8 25.4 29.8 16.1-0.2-35.1 10.9 0.6 16.1 1.7 8.2 1.7 9.6 7.6 16.2 2.9 10.4-7.5 31.5-13.2 34.2-11.6 2.2 1.4-13.1 9.2-13.8 13.4-1.4 9.3-6.8 21.8-4.3 20.2 12.6-8.4 27.5-32.3 19.2-9.2-0.4 1.1-0.9 8.2-2.6 11.1-4.2 7.1-12.2 12.6-10.4 12.5 38.9-2.1 39.2-13.5 13.9 15.6-4.8 5.5 18.2-5.8 13.2 0z" >   
   
  </path>
  
                  <!-- Орбита вращения планеты -->
  
  <path id="orbita" transform="translate(-1,0)" d="m77.6 69.4c3.3-5.1 7.3-9.8 11.4-14.4 4.5-5.1 9.2-10.2 14.4-14.7 3.8-3.3 7.9-6.5 12.3-9 3.9-2.2 7.9-4.4 12.3-5.1 4.6-0.7 9.8-1 13.8 1.2 4.4 2.4 7.3 7.3 9 12 2.1 5.6 1.8 12 1.2 18-0.3 2.8-1.1 5.5-2.1 8.1-7.8 21.2-17.1 42.2-29.4 61.1-9.3 14.3-20.1 27.8-33 39-2.9 2.6-6.3 4.7-9.9 6.3-3.5 1.5-7.3 2.9-11.1 3-3.7 0.1-7.8 0-10.8-2.1-4.2-2.9-6.8-8-8.1-12.9-2-7.3-0.6-15.3 0.6-22.8 1.4-8.7 4.2-17.3 7.5-25.5 5.9-14.7 13.3-28.9 21.9-42.2z" style="fill:none;stroke:grey; stroke-width:2"/>
  
                 <!-- Правая половинка солнца -->

 <path id="sunR" fill="#FF6600"  d="m106.4 38.5c-6.3 4.8-12.1 10.7-15.5 14.9-5.5 6.6-11.7 13.6-16.5 21.1-6.1 9.6-10.8 20-15.4 30.4-3.3 7.4-6.5 14.8-8.6 22.6-1.3 4.6-2.7 9.5-2.4 14.1 0.4 5.8 12.4 13.2 20.4 17.1 9.7 4.8 21 8.1 31.8 6.9 16.7-1.9 34.3-9.1 45.5-21.6 10.4-11.6 16-28.5 15.3-44-0.7-16.1-8.6-32.4-19.8-44-9-9.3-31.3-20-34.8-17.4z" /> 
                 <!-- Левая половинка солнца -->
 <path id="sunL" fill="#FF6600"   d="m45.8 140.1c1.6-8.4 1.9-10.1 3.3-15.1 1.5-5.4 3.2-10.8 5.2-16 2.6-6.7 5.8-13.1 9.1-19.5 3.1-5.9 6.6-11.7 10.3-17.2 3.6-5.4 7.3-10.8 11.5-15.7 5.4-6.3 12.6-13.1 17.5-17.8 4.2-4.1-29.9 1.1-41.5 9.3-23.1 16.4-27.9 35.8-28.9 52-0.4 7.1 1.1 15.8 3.7 23.2 2.1 6.1 9.3 18.6 9.6 16.9z" />  
            <!-- Анимация вращения планеты -->
 <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="14"  fill="url(#gradEarth)" >
   <animateMotion begin="btn1.click" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#orbita" />
   </animateMotion>
 </circle>    
         <!-- Дополнительная маскирующая зона солнца, чтобы не было видно вращения планеты с обратной строны солнца -->
 <path id="sunR2" fill="#FF6600" d="m112.1 49.9c-6.3 4.8-8.2 7.1-11.6 11.3-5.5 6.6-10.3 12.7-14.7 19.6-5.5 8.7-10.2 18-14.5 27.4-3.2 7.2-5.7 14.6-8.3 22-2.2 6.2-6.3 14.3-6 18.9 0.4 5.8 6.9 7.4 11.4 9.6 9.7 4.8 21 8.1 31.8 6.9 16.7-1.9 34.3-9.1 45.5-21.6 10.4-11.6 16-28.5 15.3-44-0.7-16.1-7.2-34-19.8-44-7.7-6.2-25.6-8.6-29.1-6z" />
    
                    <!-- Включение видимости всей анимации        -->
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#321300" opacity="1" >
   <set attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click" to="0" />
   </rect>
        <!-- Кнопка -->
 <g id="btn1" onclick='play()' transform="translate(0 0)" >
  <circle  cx="180" cy="185" r="8" fill="url(#gradEarth)"  /> 
  <text id="txt1" x="150" y="170" font-size="1.2rem" fill="gold" >Start</text>
 </g>  
</svg>
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 10 200 200" > 

<defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow2" 
  x="-20%" y="-20%" 
  width="150%" height="150%">
  <feGaussianBlur   stdDeviation="2" />
  </filter> 
       <!-- Эффект колыхания огня для протуберанцев солнца -->
       <filter id="myFilter" >
      <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.0005" numOctaves="5" result="turbulence" >
     <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="32s" values="0.0005;0.02;0.0005;0.02;0.0005" begin="btn1.click" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
      </feTurbulence>
    <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter> 
       <!-- Анимация градиента языков пламени -->
   <radialGradient id="gradSun">
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="yellow">
   <animate attributeName="offset" values="80%;20%;40%;10%;80%" begin="btn1.click" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="gold" >
  <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="gold;#FF6200;gold" begin="btn1.click" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </stop>
      </radialGradient>
      
      <!-- Градиент окраски вращающейся планеты -->
   <linearGradient id="gradEarth">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen" ></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>     
   
         <!-- Фон -->
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#321300" /> 
 
          <!-- Протуберанцы солнца 1-ая группа -->
  <path id="flame"  class="flame" fill="url(#gradSun)" filter="url(#myFilter)" d="m181.9 82.8c-27.3 31.7 13 43-4.1 40.5-9.2-1.4-38.7 12.5-18 26.4 20.5 13.7-30-2.1-20.1 12.9 14.2 21.5-18.3-8.9-23 9.3-7.4 28.2-10.9 1.8-16.6 1.8-6.6 0-13.6 13.2-19.2-2.4-3.8-10.7-27.1-14.7-33.7 3.2-3.2 8.6-10.1-48-13.3-39.3C19.4 174.7 36.3 104.4 26.1 108.6 0.8 119.1 33.6 83.8 32.5 75.7 30.3 59.4 20.1 39.8 24.6 45.2 32.4 54.4 52.8 48.8 48.8 43.5 36.6 27.5 38.2 21 36.2 18.9 19.8 1.4 76 39.7 74.2 33.7 71.5 25.1 68.3 8.7 70.3 10.1c7.1 5 29.8 25.4 29.8 16.1-0.2-35.1 10.9 0.6 16.1 1.7 8.2 1.7 9.6 7.6 16.2 2.9 10.4-7.5 31.5-13.2 34.2-11.6 2.2 1.4-13.1 9.2-13.8 13.4-1.4 9.3-6.8 21.8-4.3 20.2 12.6-8.4 27.5-32.3 19.2-9.2-0.4 1.1-0.9 8.2-2.6 11.1-4.2 7.1-12.2 12.6-10.4 12.5 38.9-2.1 39.2-13.5 13.9 15.6-4.8 5.5 18.2-5.8 13.2 0z" >   
   
  </path>
  
                  <!-- Орбита вращения планеты -->
  
  <path id="orbita" transform="translate(-1,0)" d="m77.6 69.4c3.3-5.1 7.3-9.8 11.4-14.4 4.5-5.1 9.2-10.2 14.4-14.7 3.8-3.3 7.9-6.5 12.3-9 3.9-2.2 7.9-4.4 12.3-5.1 4.6-0.7 9.8-1 13.8 1.2 4.4 2.4 7.3 7.3 9 12 2.1 5.6 1.8 12 1.2 18-0.3 2.8-1.1 5.5-2.1 8.1-7.8 21.2-17.1 42.2-29.4 61.1-9.3 14.3-20.1 27.8-33 39-2.9 2.6-6.3 4.7-9.9 6.3-3.5 1.5-7.3 2.9-11.1 3-3.7 0.1-7.8 0-10.8-2.1-4.2-2.9-6.8-8-8.1-12.9-2-7.3-0.6-15.3 0.6-22.8 1.4-8.7 4.2-17.3 7.5-25.5 5.9-14.7 13.3-28.9 21.9-42.2z" style="fill:none;stroke:grey; stroke-width:2"/>
  
                 <!-- Правая половинка солнца -->

 <path id="sunR" fill="#FF6600"  d="m106.4 38.5c-6.3 4.8-12.1 10.7-15.5 14.9-5.5 6.6-11.7 13.6-16.5 21.1-6.1 9.6-10.8 20-15.4 30.4-3.3 7.4-6.5 14.8-8.6 22.6-1.3 4.6-2.7 9.5-2.4 14.1 0.4 5.8 12.4 13.2 20.4 17.1 9.7 4.8 21 8.1 31.8 6.9 16.7-1.9 34.3-9.1 45.5-21.6 10.4-11.6 16-28.5 15.3-44-0.7-16.1-8.6-32.4-19.8-44-9-9.3-31.3-20-34.8-17.4z" /> 
                 <!-- Левая половинка солнца -->
 <path id="sunL" fill="#FF6600"   d="m45.8 140.1c1.6-8.4 1.9-10.1 3.3-15.1 1.5-5.4 3.2-10.8 5.2-16 2.6-6.7 5.8-13.1 9.1-19.5 3.1-5.9 6.6-11.7 10.3-17.2 3.6-5.4 7.3-10.8 11.5-15.7 5.4-6.3 12.6-13.1 17.5-17.8 4.2-4.1-29.9 1.1-41.5 9.3-23.1 16.4-27.9 35.8-28.9 52-0.4 7.1 1.1 15.8 3.7 23.2 2.1 6.1 9.3 18.6 9.6 16.9z" />  
            <!-- Анимация вращения планеты -->
 <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="12"  fill="url(#gradEarth)" >
   <animateMotion begin="btn1.click" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#orbita" />
   </animateMotion> 
          <!-- Анимация вращения планеты вокруг своей оси -->
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="1.5s" values="0 0 0;360 0 0 " repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </circle>    
         <!-- Дополнительная маскирующая зона солнца, чтобы не было видно вращения планеты с обратной строны солнца -->
 <path id="sunR2" fill="#FF6600" d="m112.1 49.9c-6.3 4.8-8.2 7.1-11.6 11.3-5.5 6.6-10.3 12.7-14.7 19.6-5.5 8.7-10.2 18-14.5 27.4-3.2 7.2-5.7 14.6-8.3 22-2.2 6.2-6.3 14.3-6 18.9 0.4 5.8 6.9 7.4 11.4 9.6 9.7 4.8 21 8.1 31.8 6.9 16.7-1.9 34.3-9.1 45.5-21.6 10.4-11.6 16-28.5 15.3-44-0.7-16.1-7.2-34-19.8-44-7.7-6.2-25.6-8.6-29.1-6z" />
    
                    <!-- Включение видимости всей анимации        -->
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#321300" opacity="1" >
   <set attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click" to="0" />
   </rect>
        <!-- Кнопка -->
 <g id="btn1"  >
  <circle  cx="180" cy="185" r="8" fill="url(#gradEarth)"  /> 
  <text id="txt1" x="150" y="170" font-size="1.2rem" fill="gold" >Start</text>
 </g>  
</svg>
```

### Вариант #3

Всё тоже самое, как во втором варианте. Добавляется второй паттерн языков пламени. 
Два паттерна вращаются в разные стороны.

```
.flame {
transform-origin: center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: rotate-sun 40s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-sun {
0% {transform: rotateX(0deg)}
100% {transform: rotateZ(360deg);}

} 

.flame2 {
transform-origin: center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: rotate-sun2 28s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-sun2 {
0% {transform: rotateX(360deg)}
100% {transform: rotateZ(0deg);}

}
```

Ниже полный код:

```css
.flame {
transform-origin: center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: rotate-sun 40s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-sun {
0% {transform: rotateX(0deg)}
100% {transform: rotateZ(360deg);}

} 

.flame2 {
transform-origin: center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: rotate-sun2 28s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-sun2 {
0% {transform: rotateX(360deg)}
100% {transform: rotateZ(0deg);}

}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 10 200 200" > 

<defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow2" 
  x="-20%" y="-20%" 
  width="150%" height="150%">
  <feGaussianBlur   stdDeviation="2" />
  </filter> 
       <!-- Эффект колыхания огня для протуберанцов солнца -->
       <filter id="myFilter" >
      <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.0001" numOctaves="5" result="turbulence" >
     <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="32s" values="0.0005;0.02;0.0005;0.02;0.0005" begin="btn1.click" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
      </feTurbulence>
    <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter> 
       <!-- Анимация градиента языков пламени -->
   <radialGradient id="gradSun">
        <stop offset="20%" stop-color="yellow">
   <animate attributeName="offset" values="80%;20%;40%;10%;80%" begin="btn1.click" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="gold" >
  <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="gold;#FF6200;gold" begin="btn1.click" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </stop>
      </radialGradient>
      
      <!-- Градиент окраски вращающейся планеты -->
   <linearGradient id="gradEarth">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen" ></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>     
   
         <!-- Фон -->
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#321300" /> 
 
          <!-- Протуберанцы солнца -->
  <path id="flame"  class="flame" fill="url(#gradSun)" filter="url(#myFilter)" d="m181.9 82.8c-27.3 31.7 13 43-4.1 40.5-9.2-1.4-38.7 12.5-18 26.4 20.5 13.7-30-2.1-20.1 12.9 14.2 21.5-18.3-8.9-23 9.3-7.4 28.2-10.9 1.8-16.6 1.8-6.6 0-13.6 13.2-19.2-2.4-3.8-10.7-27.1-14.7-33.7 3.2-3.2 8.6-10.1-48-13.3-39.3C19.4 174.7 36.3 104.4 26.1 108.6 0.8 119.1 33.6 83.8 32.5 75.7 30.3 59.4 20.1 39.8 24.6 45.2 32.4 54.4 52.8 48.8 48.8 43.5 36.6 27.5 38.2 21 36.2 18.9 19.8 1.4 76 39.7 74.2 33.7 71.5 25.1 68.3 8.7 70.3 10.1c7.1 5 29.8 25.4 29.8 16.1-0.2-35.1 10.9 0.6 16.1 1.7 8.2 1.7 9.6 7.6 16.2 2.9 10.4-7.5 31.5-13.2 34.2-11.6 2.2 1.4-13.1 9.2-13.8 13.4-1.4 9.3-6.8 21.8-4.3 20.2 12.6-8.4 27.5-32.3 19.2-9.2-0.4 1.1-0.9 8.2-2.6 11.1-4.2 7.1-12.2 12.6-10.4 12.5 38.9-2.1 39.2-13.5 13.9 15.6-4.8 5.5 18.2-5.8 13.2 0z" >   
  
 
          <!-- Анимация роста, уменьшения Протуберанцев солнца -->
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
      type="scale"
      begin="btn1.click"
      dur="6s"
      values="0.6;0.7;0.7;0.7;0.5;1"
      repeatCount="indefinite"  />
  
  </path>
        <!-- Протуберанцы солнца 2-ая группа -->
  <path id="flame2"  class="flame2" fill="url(#gradSun)" filter="url(#myFilter)" d="m181.9 82.8c-27.3 31.7 13 43-4.1 40.5-9.2-1.4-38.7 12.5-18 26.4 20.5 13.7-30-2.1-20.1 12.9 14.2 21.5-18.3-8.9-23 9.3-7.4 28.2-10.9 1.8-16.6 1.8-6.6 0-13.6 13.2-19.2-2.4-3.8-10.7-27.1-14.7-33.7 3.2-3.2 8.6-10.1-48-13.3-39.3C19.4 174.7 36.3 104.4 26.1 108.6 0.8 119.1 33.6 83.8 32.5 75.7 30.3 59.4 20.1 39.8 24.6 45.2 32.4 54.4 52.8 48.8 48.8 43.5 36.6 27.5 38.2 21 36.2 18.9 19.8 1.4 76 39.7 74.2 33.7 71.5 25.1 68.3 8.7 70.3 10.1c7.1 5 29.8 25.4 29.8 16.1-0.2-35.1 10.9 0.6 16.1 1.7 8.2 1.7 9.6 7.6 16.2 2.9 10.4-7.5 31.5-13.2 34.2-11.6 2.2 1.4-13.1 9.2-13.8 13.4-1.4 9.3-6.8 21.8-4.3 20.2 12.6-8.4 27.5-32.3 19.2-9.2-0.4 1.1-0.9 8.2-2.6 11.1-4.2 7.1-12.2 12.6-10.4 12.5 38.9-2.1 39.2-13.5 13.9 15.6-4.8 5.5 18.2-5.8 13.2 0z" />  
                  <!-- Орбита вращения планеты -->
  
  <path id="orbita" transform="translate(-1,0)" d="m77.6 69.4c3.3-5.1 7.3-9.8 11.4-14.4 4.5-5.1 9.2-10.2 14.4-14.7 3.8-3.3 7.9-6.5 12.3-9 3.9-2.2 7.9-4.4 12.3-5.1 4.6-0.7 9.8-1 13.8 1.2 4.4 2.4 7.3 7.3 9 12 2.1 5.6 1.8 12 1.2 18-0.3 2.8-1.1 5.5-2.1 8.1-7.8 21.2-17.1 42.2-29.4 61.1-9.3 14.3-20.1 27.8-33 39-2.9 2.6-6.3 4.7-9.9 6.3-3.5 1.5-7.3 2.9-11.1 3-3.7 0.1-7.8 0-10.8-2.1-4.2-2.9-6.8-8-8.1-12.9-2-7.3-0.6-15.3 0.6-22.8 1.4-8.7 4.2-17.3 7.5-25.5 5.9-14.7 13.3-28.9 21.9-42.2z" style="fill:none;stroke:grey; stroke-width:2"/>
  
                 <!-- Правая половинка солнца -->

 <path id="sunR" fill="#FF6600"  d="m106.4 38.5c-6.3 4.8-12.1 10.7-15.5 14.9-5.5 6.6-11.7 13.6-16.5 21.1-6.1 9.6-10.8 20-15.4 30.4-3.3 7.4-6.5 14.8-8.6 22.6-1.3 4.6-2.7 9.5-2.4 14.1 0.4 5.8 12.4 13.2 20.4 17.1 9.7 4.8 21 8.1 31.8 6.9 16.7-1.9 34.3-9.1 45.5-21.6 10.4-11.6 16-28.5 15.3-44-0.7-16.1-8.6-32.4-19.8-44-9-9.3-31.3-20-34.8-17.4z" /> 
                 <!-- Левая половинка солнца -->
 <path id="sunL" fill="#FF6600"   d="m45.8 140.1c1.6-8.4 1.9-10.1 3.3-15.1 1.5-5.4 3.2-10.8 5.2-16 2.6-6.7 5.8-13.1 9.1-19.5 3.1-5.9 6.6-11.7 10.3-17.2 3.6-5.4 7.3-10.8 11.5-15.7 5.4-6.3 12.6-13.1 17.5-17.8 4.2-4.1-29.9 1.1-41.5 9.3-23.1 16.4-27.9 35.8-28.9 52-0.4 7.1 1.1 15.8 3.7 23.2 2.1 6.1 9.3 18.6 9.6 16.9z" />  
            <!-- Анимация вращения планеты -->
 <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="12"  fill="url(#gradEarth)" >
   <animateMotion begin="btn1.click" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#orbita" />
   </animateMotion> 
           <!-- Анимация вращения планеты вокруг своей оси -->
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="1.5s" values="0 0 0;360 0 0 " repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </circle>    
         <!-- Дополнительная маскирующая зона солнца, чтобы не было видно вращения планеты с обратной строны солнца -->
 <path id="sunR2" fill="#FF6600" d="m112.1 49.9c-6.3 4.8-8.2 7.1-11.6 11.3-5.5 6.6-10.3 12.7-14.7 19.6-5.5 8.7-10.2 18-14.5 27.4-3.2 7.2-5.7 14.6-8.3 22-2.2 6.2-6.3 14.3-6 18.9 0.4 5.8 6.9 7.4 11.4 9.6 9.7 4.8 21 8.1 31.8 6.9 16.7-1.9 34.3-9.1 45.5-21.6 10.4-11.6 16-28.5 15.3-44-0.7-16.1-7.2-34-19.8-44-7.7-6.2-25.6-8.6-29.1-6z" />
    
                    <!-- Включение видимости всей анимации        -->
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#321300" opacity="1" >
   <set attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click" to="0" />
   </rect>
        <!-- Кнопка запуска анимации -->
 <g id="btn1">
  <circle  cx="180" cy="185" r="8" fill="url(#gradEarth)"  /> 
  <text id="txt1" x="150" y="170" font-size="1.2rem" fill="gold" >Start</text>
 </g>  
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

Добавлен вариант по комментарию:

> А эту всю анимацию можно сделать, чтобы не по click работала, а
>   постоянно работала без click?

```css
.flame {
transform-origin: center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: rotate-sun 40s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-sun {
0% {transform: rotateX(0deg)}
100% {transform: rotateZ(360deg);}

} 

.flame2 {
transform-origin: center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: rotate-sun2 28s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-sun2 {
0% {transform: rotateX(360deg)}
100% {transform: rotateZ(0deg);}

}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 10 200 200" > 

<defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow2" 
  x="-20%" y="-20%" 
  width="150%" height="150%">
  <feGaussianBlur   stdDeviation="2" />
  </filter> 
       <!-- Эффект колыхания огня для протуберанцов солнца -->
       <filter id="myFilter" >
      <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.0001" numOctaves="5" result="turbulence" >
     <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="32s" values="0.0005;0.02;0.0005;0.02;0.0005" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
      </feTurbulence>
    <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="15" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter> 
       <!-- Анимация градиента языков пламени -->
   <radialGradient id="gradSun">
        <stop offset="20%" stop-color="yellow">
   <animate attributeName="offset" values="80%;20%;40%;10%;80%" begin="0s" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="gold" >
  <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="gold;#FF6200;gold" begin="0s" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </stop>
      </radialGradient>
      
      <!-- Градиент окраски вращающейся планеты -->
   <linearGradient id="gradEarth">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen" ></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>     
   
         <!-- Фон -->
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#321300" /> 
 
          <!-- Протуберанцы солнца -->
  <path id="flame"  class="flame" fill="url(#gradSun)" filter="url(#myFilter)" d="m181.9 82.8c-27.3 31.7 13 43-4.1 40.5-9.2-1.4-38.7 12.5-18 26.4 20.5 13.7-30-2.1-20.1 12.9 14.2 21.5-18.3-8.9-23 9.3-7.4 28.2-10.9 1.8-16.6 1.8-6.6 0-13.6 13.2-19.2-2.4-3.8-10.7-27.1-14.7-33.7 3.2-3.2 8.6-10.1-48-13.3-39.3C19.4 174.7 36.3 104.4 26.1 108.6 0.8 119.1 33.6 83.8 32.5 75.7 30.3 59.4 20.1 39.8 24.6 45.2 32.4 54.4 52.8 48.8 48.8 43.5 36.6 27.5 38.2 21 36.2 18.9 19.8 1.4 76 39.7 74.2 33.7 71.5 25.1 68.3 8.7 70.3 10.1c7.1 5 29.8 25.4 29.8 16.1-0.2-35.1 10.9 0.6 16.1 1.7 8.2 1.7 9.6 7.6 16.2 2.9 10.4-7.5 31.5-13.2 34.2-11.6 2.2 1.4-13.1 9.2-13.8 13.4-1.4 9.3-6.8 21.8-4.3 20.2 12.6-8.4 27.5-32.3 19.2-9.2-0.4 1.1-0.9 8.2-2.6 11.1-4.2 7.1-12.2 12.6-10.4 12.5 38.9-2.1 39.2-13.5 13.9 15.6-4.8 5.5 18.2-5.8 13.2 0z" >   
  
 
          <!-- Анимация роста, уменьшения Протуберанцев солнца -->
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
      type="scale"
      begin="0s"
      dur="6s"
      values="0.6;0.7;0.7;0.7;0.5;1"
      repeatCount="indefinite"  />
  
  </path>
        <!-- Протуберанцы солнца 2-ая группа -->
  <path id="flame2"  class="flame2" fill="url(#gradSun)" filter="url(#myFilter)" d="m181.9 82.8c-27.3 31.7 13 43-4.1 40.5-9.2-1.4-38.7 12.5-18 26.4 20.5 13.7-30-2.1-20.1 12.9 14.2 21.5-18.3-8.9-23 9.3-7.4 28.2-10.9 1.8-16.6 1.8-6.6 0-13.6 13.2-19.2-2.4-3.8-10.7-27.1-14.7-33.7 3.2-3.2 8.6-10.1-48-13.3-39.3C19.4 174.7 36.3 104.4 26.1 108.6 0.8 119.1 33.6 83.8 32.5 75.7 30.3 59.4 20.1 39.8 24.6 45.2 32.4 54.4 52.8 48.8 48.8 43.5 36.6 27.5 38.2 21 36.2 18.9 19.8 1.4 76 39.7 74.2 33.7 71.5 25.1 68.3 8.7 70.3 10.1c7.1 5 29.8 25.4 29.8 16.1-0.2-35.1 10.9 0.6 16.1 1.7 8.2 1.7 9.6 7.6 16.2 2.9 10.4-7.5 31.5-13.2 34.2-11.6 2.2 1.4-13.1 9.2-13.8 13.4-1.4 9.3-6.8 21.8-4.3 20.2 12.6-8.4 27.5-32.3 19.2-9.2-0.4 1.1-0.9 8.2-2.6 11.1-4.2 7.1-12.2 12.6-10.4 12.5 38.9-2.1 39.2-13.5 13.9 15.6-4.8 5.5 18.2-5.8 13.2 0z" />  
                  <!-- Орбита вращения планеты -->
  
  <path id="orbita" transform="translate(-1,0)" d="m77.6 69.4c3.3-5.1 7.3-9.8 11.4-14.4 4.5-5.1 9.2-10.2 14.4-14.7 3.8-3.3 7.9-6.5 12.3-9 3.9-2.2 7.9-4.4 12.3-5.1 4.6-0.7 9.8-1 13.8 1.2 4.4 2.4 7.3 7.3 9 12 2.1 5.6 1.8 12 1.2 18-0.3 2.8-1.1 5.5-2.1 8.1-7.8 21.2-17.1 42.2-29.4 61.1-9.3 14.3-20.1 27.8-33 39-2.9 2.6-6.3 4.7-9.9 6.3-3.5 1.5-7.3 2.9-11.1 3-3.7 0.1-7.8 0-10.8-2.1-4.2-2.9-6.8-8-8.1-12.9-2-7.3-0.6-15.3 0.6-22.8 1.4-8.7 4.2-17.3 7.5-25.5 5.9-14.7 13.3-28.9 21.9-42.2z" style="fill:none;stroke:grey; stroke-width:2"/>
  
                 <!-- Правая половинка солнца -->

 <path id="sunR" fill="#FF6600"  d="m106.4 38.5c-6.3 4.8-12.1 10.7-15.5 14.9-5.5 6.6-11.7 13.6-16.5 21.1-6.1 9.6-10.8 20-15.4 30.4-3.3 7.4-6.5 14.8-8.6 22.6-1.3 4.6-2.7 9.5-2.4 14.1 0.4 5.8 12.4 13.2 20.4 17.1 9.7 4.8 21 8.1 31.8 6.9 16.7-1.9 34.3-9.1 45.5-21.6 10.4-11.6 16-28.5 15.3-44-0.7-16.1-8.6-32.4-19.8-44-9-9.3-31.3-20-34.8-17.4z" /> 
                 <!-- Левая половинка солнца -->
 <path id="sunL" fill="#FF6600"   d="m45.8 140.1c1.6-8.4 1.9-10.1 3.3-15.1 1.5-5.4 3.2-10.8 5.2-16 2.6-6.7 5.8-13.1 9.1-19.5 3.1-5.9 6.6-11.7 10.3-17.2 3.6-5.4 7.3-10.8 11.5-15.7 5.4-6.3 12.6-13.1 17.5-17.8 4.2-4.1-29.9 1.1-41.5 9.3-23.1 16.4-27.9 35.8-28.9 52-0.4 7.1 1.1 15.8 3.7 23.2 2.1 6.1 9.3 18.6 9.6 16.9z" />  
            <!-- Анимация вращения планеты -->
 <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="12"  fill="url(#gradEarth)" >
   <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#orbita" />
   </animateMotion> 
          <!-- Анимация вращения планеты вокруг своей оси -->
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="1.5s" values="0 0 0;360 0 0 " repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </circle>    
         <!-- Дополнительная маскирующая зона солнца, чтобы не было видно вращения планеты с обратной строны солнца -->
 <path id="sunR2" fill="#FF6600" d="m112.1 49.9c-6.3 4.8-8.2 7.1-11.6 11.3-5.5 6.6-10.3 12.7-14.7 19.6-5.5 8.7-10.2 18-14.5 27.4-3.2 7.2-5.7 14.6-8.3 22-2.2 6.2-6.3 14.3-6 18.9 0.4 5.8 6.9 7.4 11.4 9.6 9.7 4.8 21 8.1 31.8 6.9 16.7-1.9 34.3-9.1 45.5-21.6 10.4-11.6 16-28.5 15.3-44-0.7-16.1-7.2-34-19.8-44-7.7-6.2-25.6-8.6-29.1-6z" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Мне нравится! Лучи мягкие как я хотел. движение спокойное. И с фильтром реально похоже на огонь.

Comment: Саша а эту всю анимацию можно сделать что бы не по click работала а постоянно работала без click ?

Comment: @MaximLensky заменить begin="btn1.click" на begin="0s"

Comment: Саша у меня больше одного голоса нету...я уже плюсанул

Comment: @MaximLensky Благодарю Максим

Answer (score 15):

Вариант 1

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #010101;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.system {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(75deg);
}

.sun,
.orbit,
.planet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sun,
.planet {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

.sun {
  font-size: 7em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F8E82F 0%, rgba(251, 65, 9, 1) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(255, 160, 60, .4);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.orbit {
  width: 24em;
  height: 24em;
  margin-top: -12em;
  margin-left: -12em;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
  animation: animOrbit 12s linear infinite;
}

.planet {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  left: 100%;
  animation: animPlanet 12s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animOrbit {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animPlanet {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="system">
  <div class="sun"></div>
  <div class="orbit">
    <div class="planet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #010101;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.system {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(65deg) rotateY(-65deg);
  animation: animSystem 36s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animSystem{
  0%{
    transform: rotateX(65deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotateX(65deg) rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

.sun,
.orbit,
.planet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sun,
.planet {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

.sun {
  font-size: 7em;
  background-color: #FB7209;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F8E82F 0%, rgba(251, 65, 9, 1) 100%);
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  box-shadow:
    0 0 10px 5px rgba(244, 110, 28, .6),
    0 0 20px 10px rgba(244, 110, 28, .3),
    0 0 30px 15px rgba(244, 110, 28, .1);
    animation: animSunFire 6s alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes animSunFire {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow:
      0 0 10px 5px rgba(244, 110, 28, .6),
      0 0 20px 10px rgba(244, 110, 28, .3),
      0 0 30px 15px rgba(244, 110, 28, .1);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow:
      0 0 14px 7px rgba(244, 110, 28, .6),
      0 0 28px 14px rgba(244, 110, 28, .3),
      0 0 42px 81px rgba(244, 110, 28, .1);
  }
}

.orbit {
  width: 24em;
  height: 24em;
  margin-top: -12em;
  margin-left: -12em;
  border: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
  animation: animOrbit 12s linear infinite;
}

.planet {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  left: 100%;
  animation: animPlanet 12s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animOrbit {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animPlanet {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="system">
    <div class="sun"></div>
    <div class="orbit">
      <div class="planet"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Хороший объём у солнца и glow!

Answer (score 10):

Объяснения смотрите в комментариях к коду.

Осторожно! При запуске анимации включается трек группы `Zodiac`

**UPDATE**

*Добавлена анимация вращения планеты вокруг своей оси*

```css
.flame {
transform-origin: center;
transform-box:fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 10 200 200" > 

<defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow2" 
  x="-20%" y="-20%" 
  width="150%" height="150%">
  <feGaussianBlur   stdDeviation="2" />
  </filter>   
       <!-- Анимация градиента языков пламени -->
   <radialGradient id="gradSun">
        <stop offset="20%" stop-color="yellow">
   <animate attributeName="offset" values="80%;20%;40%;10%;80%" begin="btn1.click" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="gold" >
  <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="gold;#FF6200;gold" begin="btn1.click" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </stop>
      </radialGradient>
      
      <!-- Градиент окраски вращающейся планеты -->
   <linearGradient id="gradEarth">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen" ></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>     
   
         <!-- Фон -->
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#321300" />
 <g id="btn1" onclick='play()' transform="translate(0 0)" >
  <circle  cx="180" cy="185" r="8" fill="url(#gradEarth)"  /> 
  <text id="txt1" x="150" y="170" font-size="1.2rem" fill="gold" >Start</text>
 </g>  
          <!-- Протуберанцы солнца -->
  <path id="flame" class="flame" fill="url(#gradSun)" filter="url(#dropShadow2)" d="m181.9 82.8c-27.3 31.7 13 43-4.1 40.5-9.2-1.4-38.7 12.5-18 26.4 20.5 13.7-30-2.1-20.1 12.9 14.2 21.5-18.3-8.9-23 9.3-7.4 28.2-10.9 1.8-16.6 1.8-6.6 0-13.6 13.2-19.2-2.4-3.8-10.7-27.1-14.7-33.7 3.2-3.2 8.6-10.1-48-13.3-39.3C19.4 174.7 36.3 104.4 26.1 108.6 0.8 119.1 33.6 83.8 32.5 75.7 30.3 59.4 20.1 39.8 24.6 45.2 32.4 54.4 52.8 48.8 48.8 43.5 36.6 27.5 38.2 21 36.2 18.9 19.8 1.4 76 39.7 74.2 33.7 71.5 25.1 68.3 8.7 70.3 10.1c7.1 5 29.8 25.4 29.8 16.1-0.2-35.1 10.9 0.6 16.1 1.7 8.2 1.7 9.6 7.6 16.2 2.9 10.4-7.5 31.5-13.2 34.2-11.6 2.2 1.4-13.1 9.2-13.8 13.4-1.4 9.3-6.8 21.8-4.3 20.2 12.6-8.4 27.5-32.3 19.2-9.2-0.4 1.1-0.9 8.2-2.6 11.1-4.2 7.1-12.2 12.6-10.4 12.5 38.9-2.1 39.2-13.5 13.9 15.6-4.8 5.5 18.2-5.8 13.2 0z" >  
          <!-- Анимация роста, уменьшения Протуберанцев солнца -->
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="btn1.click" dur="6s"  values="0.7;1;0.8;1;0.7;0.7" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  
                  <!-- Орбита вращения планеты -->
  
  <path id="orbita" transform="translate(-1,0)" d="m77.6 69.4c3.3-5.1 7.3-9.8 11.4-14.4 4.5-5.1 9.2-10.2 14.4-14.7 3.8-3.3 7.9-6.5 12.3-9 3.9-2.2 7.9-4.4 12.3-5.1 4.6-0.7 9.8-1 13.8 1.2 4.4 2.4 7.3 7.3 9 12 2.1 5.6 1.8 12 1.2 18-0.3 2.8-1.1 5.5-2.1 8.1-7.8 21.2-17.1 42.2-29.4 61.1-9.3 14.3-20.1 27.8-33 39-2.9 2.6-6.3 4.7-9.9 6.3-3.5 1.5-7.3 2.9-11.1 3-3.7 0.1-7.8 0-10.8-2.1-4.2-2.9-6.8-8-8.1-12.9-2-7.3-0.6-15.3 0.6-22.8 1.4-8.7 4.2-17.3 7.5-25.5 5.9-14.7 13.3-28.9 21.9-42.2z" style="fill:none;stroke:grey; stroke-width:2"/>
  
                 <!-- Правая половинка солнца -->

 <path id="sunR" fill="#FF6600"  d="m106.4 38.5c-6.3 4.8-12.1 10.7-15.5 14.9-5.5 6.6-11.7 13.6-16.5 21.1-6.1 9.6-10.8 20-15.4 30.4-3.3 7.4-6.5 14.8-8.6 22.6-1.3 4.6-2.7 9.5-2.4 14.1 0.4 5.8 12.4 13.2 20.4 17.1 9.7 4.8 21 8.1 31.8 6.9 16.7-1.9 34.3-9.1 45.5-21.6 10.4-11.6 16-28.5 15.3-44-0.7-16.1-8.6-32.4-19.8-44-9-9.3-31.3-20-34.8-17.4z" /> 
                 <!-- Левая половинка солнца -->
 <path id="sunL" fill="#FF6600"   d="m45.8 140.1c1.6-8.4 1.9-10.1 3.3-15.1 1.5-5.4 3.2-10.8 5.2-16 2.6-6.7 5.8-13.1 9.1-19.5 3.1-5.9 6.6-11.7 10.3-17.2 3.6-5.4 7.3-10.8 11.5-15.7 5.4-6.3 12.6-13.1 17.5-17.8 4.2-4.1-29.9 1.1-41.5 9.3-23.1 16.4-27.9 35.8-28.9 52-0.4 7.1 1.1 15.8 3.7 23.2 2.1 6.1 9.3 18.6 9.6 16.9z" />  
            <!-- Анимация вращения планеты -->
 <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="12"  fill="url(#gradEarth)" >
   <animateMotion begin="btn1.click" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#orbita" />
   </animateMotion>  
           <!-- Анимация вращения планеты вокруг своей оси -->
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="1.5s" begin="btn1.click" values="0 0 0;360 0 0 " repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </circle>    
         <!-- Дополнительная маскирующая зона солнца, чтобы не было видно вращения планеты с обратной строны солнца -->
 <path id="sunR2" fill="#FF6600" d="m112.1 49.9c-6.3 4.8-8.2 7.1-11.6 11.3-5.5 6.6-10.3 12.7-14.7 19.6-5.5 8.7-10.2 18-14.5 27.4-3.2 7.2-5.7 14.6-8.3 22-2.2 6.2-6.3 14.3-6 18.9 0.4 5.8 6.9 7.4 11.4 9.6 9.7 4.8 21 8.1 31.8 6.9 16.7-1.9 34.3-9.1 45.5-21.6 10.4-11.6 16-28.5 15.3-44-0.7-16.1-7.2-34-19.8-44-7.7-6.2-25.6-8.6-29.1-6z" />
    
 
</svg>  

<script>
var zodiac = new Audio();
zodiac.src = 'https://svg-art.ru/files/zodiac.mp3';

function play() {
  zodiac.play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: А что, круто. Если на основе этой идеи сделать например 3 слоя с лучиками, и ещё их смещать покругу, думаю очень даже ничего получится. Пишу это так  как вообще не мог понять как лучики сделать нормально. Кстати можно даже не разные рисовать а тот символ что ты сделал 3 раза применить с разным поворотом. Спасибо!

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин могу попробовать дополнительный вариант сделать, как ты сказал. А почему именно 3 слоя, вполне хватит двух слоев и сделать разное время анимации поворота, плюс анимация увеличения языков пламени, в итоге будут не повторяющиеся комбинации. Можно сделать анимацию черных пятен на солнце. Тут много, чего можно напридумывать.

Comment: Да, было бы классно! Думаю можно и двух. Сказал трёх, так как 3 точно дадут необходимое количество неповторяющихся паттернов. Но возможно и два дадут. Чёрных пятнен не хочется. Но что-нибудь такое на поверхности хотелось бы. Может какой-то фильтр тоже с анимацией, пока даже не знаю. Хотя оно и так хорошо смотрится на самом деле. Я уже подумываю от всполохов и отказаться. Если делать то главное что бы не напряжно было, скажем так нежно. Ну всмысле что бы мозг не взрывало :)

Answer (score 10):

Добавил в [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1082458/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5#1082552) от **[soledar10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13968/soledar10)** немного "косметики":

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #010101;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.system {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(80deg) rotateY(-20deg);
}

.sun,
.orbit,
.planet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sun,
.planet {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

.sun {
  font-size: 6em;
  background: radial-gradient(7em 1.2em, #944c05 1%, #b3a250 100%);
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  animation: animSun 8s linear infinite;
}

.orbit {
  width: 24em;
  height: 24em;
  margin-top: -12em;
  margin-left: -12em;
  border: 2px dotted rgba(100, 100, 100, .8);
  animation: animOrbit 12s linear infinite;
}

.planet {
  background-color: #af8d27;
  left: 100%;
  animation: animPlanet 12s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animSun {
  0%, 100% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -5px #Fa0, -4px -2px 15px -5px #FFEB3B, inset 0px 2px 15px -5px #FF5722; }
  25% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px -5px #Fa0, 4px -2px 15px -5px #FFC107, inset -1px 0px 15px -5px #FFEB3B; }
  50% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -5px #Fa0, 2px 4px 15px -5px #FF5722, inset 0px -2px 15px -5px #FF9800; }
  75% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px -5px #Fa0, -2px 4px 15px -5px #FFEB3B, inset 2px 0px 15px -5px #FFC107; }
}

@keyframes animOrbit {
  0% { transform: rotateZ(180deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateZ(-180deg); }
}

@keyframes animPlanet {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(1.5);
    box-shadow: -6px 0px 18px -5px #Fa0, inset -27px 0 14px 5px black;
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(270deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(2.0);
    box-shadow: -6px 0px 18px -5px #Fa0, inset 0px 0 2px 27px black;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(1.5);
    box-shadow: 6px 0px 18px -5px #Fa0, inset 27px 0 14px 5px black;
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(.75);
    box-shadow: 6px 0px 18px -5px #Fa0, inset 0px 0 1px 2px black;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(1.5);
    box-shadow: -6px 0px 18px -5px #Fa0, inset -27px 0 14px 5px black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="system">
  <div class="sun"></div>
  <div class="orbit">
    <div class="planet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а она там есть =)

Comment: красиво....очень

Answer (score 6):

Вот такая сценка на three.js:

```js
let base64prefix = 'data:image/png;base64,'
    let blue = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkuPn/PwAFkgLZdUNuXwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
    let blue2= 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkqPz/HwAEcgJ5UUczUQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
    let orange = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8H8PwHwAGGQJcoBRfLQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
    

    
let solarsystem = [{
        texture: blue,
        name: 'earth', radius: 2, orbit: 30, speed: 2,
        satellites: [{
            texture: blue2, rotation: [1, 1, 1],
            name: 'rock', radius: 0.5, orbit: 4, speed: 5,
        },{
            texture: blue2,
            name: 'moon', radius: 1, orbit: 6, speed: 1,
        }]
    }, {
        texture: orange,
        name: 'mars', radius: 2, orbit: 50, speed: 1,
        satellites: [{
            texture: blue2,
            name: 'phobos', radius: 0.5, orbit: 3, speed: 1,
        }, {
            texture: blue2,
            name: 'deimos', radius: 0.5, orbit: 4, speed: 3,
        }]
    }];
   
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( innerWidth, innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// planets
solarsystem.forEach(d => create(d, scene));

// sun
let sun = sphere({radius:3, orbit:0, texture: orange});
scene.add(sun)

scene.add(starfield())

function starfield() {
  let vertices = [];
  for ( let i = 0; i < 50000; i ++ ) {
    let x = Math.random()*1000-500;
    let y = Math.random()*1000-500;
    let z = Math.random()*1000-500;
    if (x*x+y*y+z*z > 1e5)
    vertices.push( x, y, z );
  }
  
  let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  geometry.setAttribute( 'position', 
    new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
  let material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
  return new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
}

function create(d, target) {
   var o = new THREE.Object3D(d.name);
   d.rotation && o.rotateX(d.rotation[0]);
   d.rotation && o.rotateY(d.rotation[1]);
   d.rotation && o.rotateZ(d.rotation[2]);
   o.add(orbit(d));
   let p = sphere(d)
   o.add(p);
   d.satellites && d.satellites.forEach(d1 => create(d1, p))
   target.add(o);
   d.o=o; 
}

function orbit(d) {
    var o = new THREE.Object3D('orbit '+ d.name);
    o.rotateX(Math.PI/2);
    o.add( new THREE.Line( 
        new THREE.CircleGeometry( d.orbit, 64 ), 
        new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } ) ));
    return o;
}

function sphere(d){
    var o = new THREE.Object3D('sphere ' + d.name);
    o.translateX(d.orbit);
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load( base64prefix + d.texture, function ( texture ) {
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( d.radius, 20, 20 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { 
            map: texture
        } );
        o.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) );
    } );    
    return o;
}

camera.position.set(25,25,25);

new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

let t = 0
function render(dt) {
    
    let t2 = dt - t;
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    solarsystem.forEach(upd);
    sun.rotateY(t2/1000);
    t = dt;
    
    function upd(d) {
        d.o.rotateY(t2/10000*d.speed);
        d.satellites && d.satellites.forEach(upd)
    }
}

requestAnimationFrame( render );
addEventListener('resize', () => {
  renderer.setSize( innerWidth, innerHeight );
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})
```

```css
body, canvas { 
    margin: 0;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Отличный ответ. Подходит больше к Solar system Поздравляю с золотым молотком SVG!

Answer (score 5):

Размумеется что не моё:  [codepen](https://codepen.io/streetjo/pen/xwvVgR)

```js
var gl;
var pwgl = {};
pwgl.ongoingImageLoads = [];
var canvas;
// Variables for interactive control
var transY = 0,
  transZ = 0;
var xRot = yRot = zRot = xOffs = yOffs = drag = 0;
pwgl.listOfPressedKeys = [];
var lastTime = 0;
// Keep track of pressed down keys in a list
function createGLContext(canvas) {
  var names = ["webgl", "experimental-webgl"];
  var context = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    try {
      context = canvas.getContext(names[i]);
    } catch (e) {}
    if (context) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (context) {
    context.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
    context.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
  } else {
    alert("Failed to create WebGL context!");
  }
  return context;
}

var vertexShaderSrc =
  "attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;" +
  "attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;" +
  "attribute vec2 aTextureCoordinates;" +
  "uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;" +
  "uniform mat4 uPMatrix;" +
  "uniform mat3 uNMatrix;" +
  "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;" +
  "varying vec3 vNormalEye;" +
  "varying vec3 vPositionEye3;" +
  "void main() {" +
  // Get vertex position in eye coordinates and send to the fragment shader
  "vec4 vertexPositionEye4 = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);" +
  "vPositionEye3 = vertexPositionEye4.xyz / vertexPositionEye4.w;" +
  // Transform the normal to eye coordinates and send to fragment shader
  "vNormalEye = normalize(uNMatrix * aVertexNormal);" +
  // Transform the geometry
  "gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);" +
  "vTextureCoord = aTextureCoordinates;" +
  "}";

var fragmentShaderSrc =
  "precision mediump float;" +
  "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;" +
  "varying vec3 vNormalEye;" +
  "varying vec3 vPositionEye3;" +

  "uniform vec3 uAmbientLightColor;" +
  "uniform vec3 uDiffuseLightColor;" +
  "uniform vec3 uSpecularLightColor;" +
  "uniform vec3 uLightPosition;" +
  "uniform vec3 uSpotDirection;" +
  "uniform sampler2D uSampler;" +

  "const float shininess = 5.0;" +
  "const float spotExponent = 80.0;" +
  // cutoff angle of spot light
  "const float spotCosCutoff = 0.97;" + // corresponds to 14 degrees

  "vec3 lightWeighting = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);" +

  "void main() {" +
  // Calculate the vector (L) to the light source. 
  "vec3 vectorToLightSource = normalize(uLightPosition - vPositionEye3);" +

  // Calculate N dot L for diffuse lighting
  "float diffuseLightWeighting = max(dot(vNormalEye," +
  "vectorToLightSource), 0.0);" +

  // Only do spot and specular light calculations if we have diffuse light term.
  "if (diffuseLightWeighting > 0.0) {" +
  "float spotEffect = dot(normalize(uSpotDirection)," +
  "normalize(-vectorToLightSource));" +

  "if (spotEffect > spotCosCutoff) {" +
  "spotEffect = pow(spotEffect, spotExponent);" +

  "vec3 reflectionVector = normalize(reflect(-" +
  "vectorToLightSource,vNormalEye));" +

  // Calculate view vector (V) 
  "vec3 viewVectorEye = -normalize(vPositionEye3);" +
  "float rdotv = max(dot(reflectionVector, viewVectorEye), 0.0);" +
  "float specularLightWeighting = pow(rdotv, shininess);" +
  "lightWeighting =" +
  "spotEffect * uDiffuseLightColor * diffuseLightWeighting +" +
  "spotEffect * uSpecularLightColor * specularLightWeighting;" +
  "}" +
  "}" +

  // Add the ambient light
  "lightWeighting += uAmbientLightColor;" +

  "vec4 texelColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);" +

  // Modulate texel color with lightweighting and write as final color
  "gl_FragColor = vec4(lightWeighting.rgb * texelColor.rgb, texelColor.a);" +
  "}";

function setupShaders() {
  var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSrc);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSrc);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert("Could not initialise shaders " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
  }
  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
  pwgl.vertexPositionAttributeLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pwgl.vertexPositionAttributeLoc);
  pwgl.vertexTextureAttributeLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoordinates");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pwgl.vertexTextureAttributeLoc);
  pwgl.vertexNormalAttributeLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexNormal");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pwgl.vertexNormalAttributeLoc);
  pwgl.uniformProjMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
  pwgl.uniformMVMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
  pwgl.uniformNormalMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uNMatrix");
  pwgl.uniformSamplerLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");
  pwgl.uniformLightPositionLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram,
    "uLightPosition");
  pwgl.uniformAmbientLightColorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram,
    "uAmbientLightColor");
  pwgl.uniformDiffuseLightColorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram,
    "uDiffuseLightColor");
  pwgl.uniformSpecularLightColorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram,
    "uSpecularLightColor");
  pwgl.uniformSpotDirectionLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSpotDirection");
  pwgl.modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();
  pwgl.modelViewMatrixStack = [];
  pwgl.projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
}

function setupTextures() {
  // Texture for the Earth
  pwgl.earthTexture = gl.createTexture();
  loadImageForTexture("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josh-street/webgl-earthsatellite/master/earth.jpg", pwgl.earthTexture);
  // Texture for the satellite
  pwgl.satelliteTexture = gl.createTexture();
  loadImageForTexture("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josh-street/webgl-earthsatellite/master/satellite.png", pwgl.satelliteTexture);
}

function loadImageForTexture(url, texture) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.crossOrigin = '';
  image.onload = function() {
    pwgl.ongoingImageLoads.splice(pwgl.ongoingImageLoads.indexOf(image), 1);
    textureFinishedLoading(image, texture);
  }
  pwgl.ongoingImageLoads.push(image);
  image.src = url;
}

function textureFinishedLoading(image, texture) {
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    image);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.MIRRORED_REPEAT);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.MIRRORED_REPEAT);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function setupLights() {
  gl.uniform3fv(pwgl.uniformLightPositionLoc, [0.0, 500.0, -16.0]);
  gl.uniform3fv(pwgl.uniformSpotDirectionLoc, [0.0, -1.0, 0.0]);
  gl.uniform3fv(pwgl.uniformAmbientLightColorLoc, [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]);
  gl.uniform3fv(pwgl.uniformDiffuseLightColorLoc, [0.7, 0.7, 0.7]);
  gl.uniform3fv(pwgl.uniformSpecularLightColorLoc, [0.8, 0.8, 0.8]);
}

function pushModelViewMatrix() {
  var copyToPush = mat4.create(pwgl.modelViewMatrix);
  pwgl.modelViewMatrixStack.push(copyToPush);
}

function popModelViewMatrix() {
  if (pwgl.modelViewMatrixStack.length == 0) {
    throw "Error popModelViewMatrix() - Stack was empty ";
  }
  pwgl.modelViewMatrix = pwgl.modelViewMatrixStack.pop();
}

function uploadNormalMatrixToShader() {
  var normalMatrix = mat3.create();
  mat4.toInverseMat3(pwgl.modelViewMatrix, normalMatrix);
  mat3.transpose(normalMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix3fv(pwgl.uniformNormalMatrixLoc, false, normalMatrix);
}

function uploadModelViewMatrixToShader() {
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(pwgl.uniformMVMatrixLoc, false,
    pwgl.modelViewMatrix);
}

function uploadProjectionMatrixToShader() {
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(pwgl.uniformProjMatrixLoc, false,
    pwgl.projectionMatrix);
}

function degToRad(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

var mouseDown = false;
var lastMouseX = null;
var lastMouseY = null;
var earthRotationMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.identity(earthRotationMatrix);
var earthVertexPositionBuffer;
var earthVertexNormalBuffer;
var earthVertexTextureCoordBuffer;
var earthVertexIndexBuffer;

function setupEarthBuffers() {
  var latitudeBands = 60;
  var longitudeBands = 60;
  var radius = 5;
  var vertexPositionData = [];
  var normalData = [];
  var textureCoordData = [];
  for (var latNumber = 0; latNumber <= latitudeBands; latNumber++) {
    var theta = latNumber * Math.PI / latitudeBands;
    var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
    var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
    for (var longNumber = 0; longNumber <= longitudeBands; longNumber++) {
      var phi = longNumber * 2 * Math.PI / longitudeBands;
      var sinPhi = Math.sin(phi);
      var cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);
      var x = cosPhi * sinTheta;
      var y = cosTheta;
      var z = sinPhi * sinTheta;
      var u = 1 - (longNumber / longitudeBands);
      var v = 1 - (latNumber / latitudeBands);
      normalData.push(x);
      normalData.push(y);
      normalData.push(z);
      textureCoordData.push(u);
      textureCoordData.push(v);
      vertexPositionData.push(radius * x);
      vertexPositionData.push(radius * y);
      vertexPositionData.push(radius * z);
    }
  }
  var indexData = [];
  for (var latNumber = 0; latNumber < latitudeBands; latNumber++) {
    for (var longNumber = 0; longNumber < longitudeBands; longNumber++) {
      var first = (latNumber * (longitudeBands + 1)) + longNumber;
      var second = first + longitudeBands + 1;
      indexData.push(first);
      indexData.push(second);
      indexData.push(first + 1);
      indexData.push(second);
      indexData.push(second + 1);
      indexData.push(first + 1);
    }
  }
  earthVertexNormalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, earthVertexNormalBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normalData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  earthVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize = 3;
  earthVertexNormalBuffer.numItems = normalData.length / 3;
  earthVertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, earthVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoordData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  earthVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
  earthVertexTextureCoordBuffer.numItems = textureCoordData.length / 2;
  earthVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, earthVertexPositionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexPositionData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  earthVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
  earthVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = vertexPositionData.length / 3;
  earthVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, earthVertexIndexBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indexData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  earthVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
  earthVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = indexData.length;
}

function setupSatelliteBuffers() {
  pwgl.satelliteVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pwgl.satelliteVertexPositionBuffer);
  var satelliteVertexPosition = [
    // Front face
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, //v0
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, //v1
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, //v2
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, //v3

    // Back face
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, //v4
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, //v5
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, //v6
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, //v7

    // Left face
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, //v8
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, //v9
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, //v10
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, //v11

    // Right face
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, //12
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, //13
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, //14
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, //15

    // Top face
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, //v16
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, //v17
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, //v18
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, //v19

    // Bottom face
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, //v20
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, //v21
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, //v22
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, //v23
  ];

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(satelliteVertexPosition),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  pwgl.CUBE_VERTEX_POS_BUF_ITEM_SIZE = 3;
  pwgl.CUBE_VERTEX_POS_BUF_NUM_ITEMS = 24;

  // Setup buffer with index
  pwgl.satelliteVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pwgl.satelliteVertexIndexBuffer);

  var cubeVertexIndices = [
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, // Front face
    4, 6, 5, 4, 7, 6, // Back face
    8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, // Left face
    12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, // Right face
    16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, // Top face
    20, 22, 21, 20, 23, 22 // Bottom face
  ];

  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  pwgl.CUBE_VERTEX_INDEX_BUF_ITEM_SIZE = 1;
  pwgl.SATELLITE_VERTEX_INDEX_BUF_NUM_ITEMS = 36;

  // Setup buffer with texture coordinates
  pwgl.satelliteVertexTextureCoordinateBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pwgl.satelliteVertexTextureCoordinateBuffer);
  var textureCoordinates = [
    //Front face
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,

    // Back face
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,

    // Left face
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,

    // Right face
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,

    // Top face
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,

    // Bottom face
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
  ];

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoordinates), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  pwgl.CUBE_VERTEX_TEX_COORD_BUF_ITEM_SIZE = 2;
  pwgl.CUBE_VERTEX_TEX_COORD_BUF_NUM_ITEMS = 24;



  // Specify normals to be able to do lighting calculations
  pwgl.satelliteVertexNormalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pwgl.satelliteVertexNormalBuffer);
  var satelliteVertexNormals = [
    // Front face
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

    // Back face
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,

    // Left face
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,

    // Right face
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,

    // Top face
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,

    // Bottom face
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
  ];

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(satelliteVertexNormals),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  pwgl.CUBE_VERTEX_NORMAL_BUF_ITEM_SIZE = 3;
  pwgl.CUBE_VERTEX_NORMAL_BUF_NUM_ITEMS = 24;
}

function setupBuffers() {
  setupEarthBuffers();
  setupSatelliteBuffers();
}

function drawSatellite(texture) {
  // Bind position buffer
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pwgl.satelliteVertexPositionBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(pwgl.vertexPositionAttributeLoc,
    pwgl.CUBE_VERTEX_POS_BUF_ITEM_SIZE,
    gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  // Bind normal buffer
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pwgl.satelliteVertexNormalBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(pwgl.vertexNormalAttributeLoc,
    pwgl.CUBE_VERTEX_NORMAL_BUF_ITEM_SIZE,
    gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  // bind texture coordinate buffer
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pwgl.satelliteVertexTextureCoordinateBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(pwgl.vertexTextureAttributeLoc,
    pwgl.CUBE_VERTEX_TEX_COORD_BUF_ITEM_SIZE,
    gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Bind index buffer and draw cube
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pwgl.satelliteVertexIndexBuffer);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, pwgl.SATELLITE_VERTEX_INDEX_BUF_NUM_ITEMS,
    gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}

function drawEarth(texture) {
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, earthVertexPositionBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(pwgl.vertexPositionAttributeLoc, earthVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, earthVertexNormalBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(pwgl.vertexNormalAttributeLoc, earthVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, earthVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(pwgl.vertexTextureAttributeLoc, earthVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, earthVertexIndexBuffer);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, earthVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
var newAngle = 0;

function draw() {
  pwgl.requestId = requestAnimFrame(draw);
  var currentTime = Date.now();
  handlePressedDownKeys();
  // Update FPS if a second or more has passed since last FPS update
  if (currentTime - pwgl.previousFrameTimeStamp >= 1000) {
    pwgl.fpsCounter.innerHTML = pwgl.nbrOfFramesForFPS;
    pwgl.nbrOfFramesForFPS = 0;
    pwgl.previousFrameTimeStamp = currentTime;
  }

  mat4.translate(pwgl.modelViewMatrix, [0.0, transY, transZ],
    pwgl.modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.rotateX(pwgl.modelViewMatrix, xRot / 50, pwgl.modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.rotateY(pwgl.modelViewMatrix, yRot / 50, pwgl.modelViewMatrix);

  yRot = xRot = zRot = transY = transZ = 0;

  uploadModelViewMatrixToShader();
  uploadProjectionMatrixToShader();
  uploadNormalMatrixToShader();
  gl.uniform1i(pwgl.uniformSamplerLoc, 0);
  pushModelViewMatrix();
  var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
  if (lastTime != 0) {
    var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;
    newAngle += (90 * elapsed) / 1000;
  }
  lastTime = timeNow;
  var rotationSpeed = -degToRad(newAngle) / 50; // Sets earth rotation speed 
  mat4.rotateY(pwgl.modelViewMatrix, rotationSpeed, pwgl.modelViewMatrix);
  uploadModelViewMatrixToShader();
  uploadNormalMatrixToShader();
  drawEarth(pwgl.earthTexture);
  popModelViewMatrix();
  pushModelViewMatrix();
  if (currentTime === undefined) {
    currentTime = Date.now();
  }

  if (pwgl.animationStartTime === undefined) {
    pwgl.animationStartTime = currentTime;
  }

  pwgl.angle = (currentTime - pwgl.animationStartTime) / pwgl.orbitalMultipler * 2 * Math.PI %
    (2 * Math.PI);
  pwgl.x = Math.cos(pwgl.angle) * pwgl.circleRadius;
  pwgl.z = Math.sin(pwgl.angle) * pwgl.circleRadius;


  mat4.translate(pwgl.modelViewMatrix, [pwgl.x, pwgl.y, pwgl.z],
    pwgl.modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.scale(pwgl.modelViewMatrix, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], pwgl.modelViewMatrix);

  // CRUDE NOT WORKING FULLY 
  pwgl.satRotation = -degToRad(newAngle) * pwgl.satMultiplier;
  mat4.rotateY(pwgl.modelViewMatrix, pwgl.satRotation, pwgl.modelViewMatrix);
  uploadModelViewMatrixToShader();
  uploadNormalMatrixToShader();
  uploadProjectionMatrixToShader();
  drawSatellite(pwgl.satelliteTexture);
  popModelViewMatrix();
  pwgl.nbrOfFramesForFPS++;
}

function startup() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
  canvas = WebGLDebugUtils.makeLostContextSimulatingCanvas(canvas);
  canvas.addEventListener('webglcontextlost', handleContextLost, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('webglcontextrestored', handleContextRestored,
    false);
  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, false);
  document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mymousemove, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mymousedown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mymouseup, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel', wheelHandler, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheelHandler, false);
  gl = createGLContext(canvas);
  pwgl.fpsCounter = document.getElementById("fps");
  init();
  draw();
}

var relation = 1.6 / 2500;

function init() {
  // Initialization that is performed during first startup and when the
  // event webglcontextrestored is received is included in this function.
  setupShaders();
  setupBuffers();
  setupLights();
  setupTextures();
  // Transparent canvas for space background image
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  pwgl.x = 0.0;
  pwgl.y = 0.0;
  pwgl.z = 0.0;
  pwgl.circleRadius = 10.0;
  pwgl.orbitalMultipler = 2000;
  pwgl.satMultiplier = 2;


  // Initialize some variables related to the animation
  pwgl.animationStartTime = undefined;
  pwgl.nbrOfFramesForFPS = 0;
  pwgl.previousFrameTimeStamp = Date.now();
  mat4.perspective(30, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 1, 100.0, pwgl.projectionMatrix);
  mat4.identity(pwgl.modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.lookAt([0, 0, 50], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], pwgl.modelViewMatrix);
}

function handleContextLost(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  cancelRequestAnimFrame(pwgl.requestId);
  // Ignore all ongoing image loads by removing their onload handler
  for (var i = 0; i < pwgl.ongoingImageLoads.length; i++) {
    pwgl.ongoingImageLoads[i].onload = undefined;
  }
  pwgl.ongoingImageLoads = [];
}

function handleContextRestored(event) {
  init();
  pwgl.requestId = requestAnimFrame(draw, canvas);
}

function handleKeyDown(event) {
  pwgl.listOfPressedKeys[event.keyCode] = true;
}

function handleKeyUp(event) {
  pwgl.listOfPressedKeys[event.keyCode] = false;
}

function handlePressedDownKeys() {
  if (pwgl.listOfPressedKeys[38]) {
    // Arrow up, increase radius of circle
    if (pwgl.circleRadius < 50) {
      pwgl.circleRadius += 0.1;
    } else {
      pwgl.circleRadius = 20;
    }
  }
  if (pwgl.listOfPressedKeys[40]) {
    // Arrow down, decrease radius of circle
    pwgl.circleRadius -= 0.1;
    if (pwgl.circleRadius > 6) {
      pwgl.circleRadius -= 0.1
    } else {
      pwgl.circleRadius = 6;
    }

  }
  if (pwgl.listOfPressedKeys[37]) {
    // Left Arrow, speed up orbital speed
    pwgl.orbitalMultipler -= 20;
    var x = pwgl.orbitalMultipler * relation;
    var y = 1.6 - x;
    pwgl.satMultiplier = 1.6 + y;
    if (pwgl.orbitalMultipler < 250) {
      pwgl.orbitalMultipler = 250
    }
  }
  if (pwgl.listOfPressedKeys[39]) {
    // Right Arrow, slow down orbital speed
    pwgl.orbitalMultipler += 50;
    var x = pwgl.orbitalMultipler * relation;
    var y = 1.6 - x;
    pwgl.satMultiplier = 1.6 + y;
    console.log(pwgl.satMultiplier);
    if (pwgl.orbitalMultipler > 20000) {
      pwgl.orbitalMultipler = 20000;
    }
  }
}

function mymousedown(ev) {
  drag = 1;
  xOffs = ev.clientX;
  yOffs = ev.clientY;
}

function mymouseup(ev) {
  drag = 0;
}

function mymousemove(ev) {
  if (drag == 0) return;
  if (ev.shiftKey) {
    transZ = (ev.clientY - yOffs) / 10;
  } else if (ev.altKey) {
    transY = -(ev.clientY - yOffs) / 10;
  } else {
    yRot = -xOffs + ev.clientX;
    xRot = -yOffs + ev.clientY;
  }
  xOffs = ev.clientX;
  yOffs = ev.clientY;
}

function wheelHandler(ev) {
  if (ev.altKey) transY = -ev.detail / 10;
  else transZ = ev.detail / 10;
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josh-street/webgl-earthsatellite/master/bg.jpg");
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 0.7;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#fps-counter {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
}

#glcanvas {
  background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josh-street/webgl-earthsatellite/master/bg.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
}

#hide1 {
  display: none;
}

#hide2 {
  display: none;
}

#instructions {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  width: 24%;
  height: 12em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startup()">

  <canvas id="glcanvas" style="border: none;" width="1400" height="800"></canvas>
  <div id="fps-counter">
    <p> FPS: <span id="fps">--</span>
      <p>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/josh-street/webgl-earthsatellite/master/glMatrix.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/josh-street/webgl-earthsatellite/master/webgl/webgl-debug.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/josh-street/webgl-earthsatellite/master/webgl/webgl-utils.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: А где 1) Всполохи.
2) Лучики как огонь. Должны а) гореть...?

Comment: да я просто как пример - сори за не соответствие

Comment: @MaximLensky Я Вам просто рукоплескаю!!!! Это великолепно! Нет, серьёзно. Скопировал себе!

Answer (score 4):

Вот сообразил Вам солнышко, пока без планет

```js
let rays = (n,s) => [...Array(n)].map((_, i) =>
  `0 0 0 ${(i+s)*8}px #fd0${(i+s)===n?0:4}`
).join(',\n');

document.body.innerHTML += `
<style>
  @keyframes rays {
    0% {box-shadow:${rays(4,0)}}
    100% {box-shadow:${rays(4,1)}}
  }
</style>`;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

sun {
  margin: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 77px;
  background-color: #FFDE00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse 5s infinite, rays 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {transform: scale(1)}
  20% {transform: scale(1.03,0.97)}
  80% {transform: scale(0.97,1.03)}
  100% {transform: scale(1)}
}
```

```html
<sun></sun>
```

Comment: на эффект ripple скорее похоже

Comment: На самом деле очень круто. Получается как излучение от солнца идёт.

Comment: что за тег sun ?

Comment: @Leks обычный пользовательский тег https://learn.javascript.ru/webcomponent-core

Comment: Даже не знал что пользовательские теги можно использовать... Они как div идут? Точнее что тег писать можно знал, а вот что они как-то отображаются не знал.