# Как уменьшить нужный символ в тексте SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

Код страницы формируется динамически.
 Текст получаю в переменной, которая вставляет его в код. По этому обратиться к части текста и использовать textPath не могу.

Задача такая, уменьшить цифру после запятой. В примере с текстом 23,6 я могу сдвинуть цифру 6 вниз, а хотел бы просто сделать её маленькой.

```
<svg> 
 <text x="0" y="15 15 15 20">23,6</text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: а что в `y` означают цифры ?

Comment: Горизонтальное смещение каждого символа в тексте. Таким образом в моем примере цифра 6 сползет вниз.

Comment: круто ..это для меня новое

Comment: @СергейКазаков немного не точно объяснили.  В SVG, если даже текст 23,6 введен обычным образом, через команду <text>  то каждый символ превращается в векторный объект, который имеет координаты. Поэтому, записав `y="15 15 15 20"` оставляем первые три символа, включая запятую без изменений, а четвертый символ `6` смещаем вниз на 5 пикселей

Comment: Вот на этом свойстве отдельных координат каждого символа в слове сделал анимацию, смотрите примеры 5 и 6 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1106346/28748

Comment: покажите код, которым Вы формируете `html`

Comment: Код страницы в моем случае пишется в админке сайта умного дома [Majordomo](https://mjdm.ru). Если нужно вставить значение свойства в html, то используется такая конструкция %Объект.свойство% При открытии страницы, эта конструкция будет заменена значением. Поэтому я и не могу разбить текст как надо и использовать tspan.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться командой [tspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan), которая даст возможность применить различные стили к разным символам строки.

```html
<svg> 
 <text x="0" y="15">
  <tspan font-size="18px">23,</tspan>
  <tspan  font-size="12px"> 6</tspan>
 </text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: это ндо какую то регулярку - как regExp споткнулась об запятую так и обернула всё что после в tspan

Comment: @MaximLensky: а зачем на сервере?

Comment: ну написано что `код страницы динамический` а значит что будут проблемы с тем что бы ручками изменить

Comment: @MaximLensky: думаю, что просто неправильно сформулировано. Скорее данные динамические, а не сам код.

Comment: надо подождать автора вопроса - ему виднее

Comment: @MaximLensky конечно получится, если автор использует JS, хоть на серверной, хоть на клиентской части. JS прекрасно умеет разбить строку и добавить, поменять стили Автора вопроса, как я понял волнует, если в SVG команды позволяющие менять размер шрифта

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: а `<tspan>` может содержать вложенный `<tspan>`?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: можно даже ещё проще - обернуть в `<tspan>` только дробную часть.

Comment: @MaximLensky: про какие руки речь? Ежу морскому понятно, что скриптом всё делается.

Comment: @MaximLensky: это потому, что метка единственная - SVG :)

Comment: Данные, а именно текст, на страницу подставляются при сборке этой страницы. Поэтому и написал, что динамические. И поэтому же не могу применить <tspan>.  Текст 23,6 вставляется в код страницы.

Comment: Можно конечно на сервере сделать разные переменные, и отправлять их при сборке страницы, но делать это ради виджета, в моем именно варианте, просто не целесообразно.

Comment: Я привел вариант, как сместить цифру 6 вниз не разбивая исходного текста 23,6. Возможно есть ещё варианты с масштабом, но я не могу найти ничего подобного.

Comment: @MaximLensky да, выходит что так. Когда я нашел как двигать символы в тексте, подумал, что с размером тоже не будет трудности. Но увы.

Comment: @MaximLensky интуитивно так и подумал, но пока что не нашел.