# Как можно анимировать цветовые круги SVG?

Tags: css, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Есть концентрические круги.

- Необходимо анимировать круги и их цвета.
- Анимация может идти только по цветам и размеру кругов, без изменения их центра.
- Использовать надо нативные возможности CSS, SVG, SMIL, без использования JavaScript.

```js
const svg = document.getElementById("svg");
const SVGNameSpace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const length = 100;
const number = 5;
const dist = length / number;

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  const krug = document.createElementNS(SVGNameSpace, "circle");
  krug.setAttribute("r", length - dist * i);
  krug.setAttribute("fill", `hsl(${50 + i*50},75%,85%)`);
  svg.appendChild(krug);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="178" height="178" version="2" viewBox="-101 -101 202 202" preserveAspectRatio="none">
</svg>
```

Comment: Надо придумать. Это 70% вопроса.

Comment: может как тут? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1082656/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ подобное было бы очень хорошо, только тут цветов много, мне пока не понятно как такое реализовать, но визуально нравится.

Answer (score 4):

Можно добавить немного `scale` + `hue-rotate`

```js
let circle = (_,i) => `<circle r='${100-20*i}' style='--h:${50+i*50}; --d:${2*i}s' />`
document.getElementById("svg").innerHTML = [...Array(5)].map(circle).join('');
```

```css
svg {
  animation: color 5s infinite;
}

circle {
  animation: pulse 7s var(--d) infinite linear;
  fill: hsl(var(--h), 75%, 75%);
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%, 50%, 100% {transform: scale(1)}
  25% {transform: scale(1.05)}
  75% {transform: scale(0.95)}
}

@keyframes color {
  0%, 100%  {filter: hue-rotate(-20deg)}
  50% {filter: hue-rotate(20deg)}
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="178" height="178" viewBox="-111 -111 222 222" preserveAspectRatio="none">
</svg>
```

Comment: Интересно. Буду думать как сделать на основании идеи с той ссылки что ты прислал. Где круги как бы из центра идут. Это интересна, спасибо за ответ. может пригодиться. Теперь точно определился с тем, что хочу, как излучение из центра, как по ссылке в комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: Постараюсь сделать ответ. Думаю тут нужно расширение круга + увеличение opacity, и потом по кругу как-то зацепить. Всю схему пока до конца не понимаю, но в целом уже более ясно.

Comment: Понравилось что у тебя код более компактный для генерации кругов. Я больше люблю чисто через DOM, но для таких ситуаций интересный вариант.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин а я всегда конкатенацией делаю, меньше кода и подводных камней, вроде указания нэймспейса